# Updating to Marionette Driver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

Ok so as many of you fellow webdriver testers know the release of Firefox 47 has broken the Webdriver.FirefoxDriver. All the documentation I can find tells me that the new FirefoxDriver is Marionette.

So I have downloaded the latest executable from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 
renamed to wires.exe and moved into my test directory.

Here is my setup method

```
[TestFixture("chrome")]
[TestFixture("firefox")]
//[TestFixture("internet explorer")]
[Category("ExistingUser")]
public class ExistingUserTestSuite
{
    public string browser;
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public UserInfo User { get; set; }
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ExistingUserTest");

    public ExistingUserTestSuite(string browser)
    {
        this.browser = browser;
    }



    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "chrome":
                Driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "firefox":
                FirefoxOptions op1 = new FirefoxOptions();
                op1.IsMarionette = true;
                op1.AddAdditionalCapability("marionette", true);
                Driver = new FirefoxDriver(op1);
                break;
```

When I try to run I get the following exception. I can see that the wire.exe process is running in process explorer when I start the tests.

```
Test Name:  ChangePlan
Test FullName:  POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite("firefox").ChangePlan
Test Source:    c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs : line 359
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0000001

Result Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : entity not found
```

Here is the stack trace generating the exception

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
   at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite.SetUp() in c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs:line 56
```

Most advice I see is regarding making sure your system path is updated. I feel this is not the case here as if I remove the wire.exe from my test/bin/debug folder I get the following exception.

```
Test Name:  ChangePlan
Test FullName:  POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite("firefox").ChangePlan
Test Source:    c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs : line 359
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0000001

Result Message: OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The wires.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/jgraham/wires/releases.
```

This tells me that I am finding the driver but for some reason cannot create an instance of `FirefoxDriver()`.

Not sure what to do here, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after what felt like a wild goose hunt I found this little gem in an open issue on the geckodriver github page. I have confirmed that this has fixed my issue and now I am able to create an instance of firefox driver and successfully open Firefox 47. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/91

Here is a snippet of the code from the above URL in case the link goes dead

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Hope this helps others. But there is a bug which is currently a blocking issue for all my tests. All of my tests access our internal test environments which have self signed certs and there is a bug with marionette where you cannot handle these. 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196

=(

Comment: @JeffC - Done thanks for the reminder meant to do this when I answered it.

Comment: @JoshuaBurns It's better to include a snippet of the solution, just in case the links went down.

Comment: @SyakurRahman - Thanks for the tip, updated with the snippet.